# add reminder to Google Calendar

Tags: groovy, google-calendar-api

I have worked out how to add a reminder after setting a CalendarEventEntry using

```
insertedEntry = myService.insert( postUrl, myEntry )
reminder = new Reminder()
reminder.setMethod( Reminder$Method.ALERT )
//foo
insertedEntry.getReminder().add( reminder )
insertedEntry.update()
```

but if you update it becomes an EventEntry and the getReminder returns null and whatever you do it wipes all reminders

```
insertedEntry = myService.update(editUrl, myEntry)
```

can find nothing in the api or docs about this case.

Anyone solved this already??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to cast the update result ?

```
BaseEntry updateEntry = myService.update(editUrl, myEntry)
if (updatedEntry instanceOf CalendarEventEntry) {
    insertEntry = (CalendarEventEntry) updatedEntry
}
```

Comment: i fixed this by doing the update() the immediately running a query on it, and then you have to add the reminder to the query. REALY coutner intuitive...

Comment: <code>    EventEntry editEntry = myService.update(editUrl, myEntry)
 result = editEntry.getSelfLink().getHref()
 myQuery = new CalendarQuery(postUrl)
 CalendarEventFeed evFeed = myService.query( myQuery, CalendarEventFeed.class )
 CalendarEventEntry calEntry = evFeed.getEntries().get(0)</code>

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply update it with:

```
insertedEntry.update()
```

rather than

```
insertedEntry = myService.update(editUrl, myEntry)
```